# Determine amount of memory allocated by specific .NET assembly

Tags: .net, performance, memory-management, profiling

I want to measure the memory allocation of specific managed assemblies in my program.
Is there a way/tool to determine the amount of memory which is allocated by a specific managed assembly at runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CLR has allocation tick ETL event, but it's only fired once every 100Kb allocation. If your program runs long enough (allocates enough memory), then the data could be quite accurate.

You can view the callstacks of allocation tick events using Perfview (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28567).